# How to scroll to a specific element in a StackPanel?

Tags: c#, wpf, children, visible, stackpanel

I created a vertical StackPanel and added a large number of Child elements. Each Child has a different height. How can I scroll to a specific child? What if a Child is not visible e.g. due to being located at the bottom of the list.

Comment: Please revise your phrasing; I cannot understand what you are asking.

Comment: If you want to have all children visible, I recommend using a `WrapPanel` rather than a `StackPanel`

Comment: Try using EnsureVisible() - http://www.geekpedia.com/KB63_Using-EnsureVisible()-to-scroll-down-to-the-bottom-of-a-ListView.html

Comment: Are you asking how to scroll to a specific item in a layout that uses a scrollbar?

Comment: @DanPuzey
Yes exactly.
Something similar to this function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.listview.ensurevisible.aspx

Comment: Could you use a LisBox and ScrollIntoView?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.scrollintoview.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [`StackPanel.MakeVisible(Visual visual, Rect rectangle)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.stackpanel.makevisible%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method by passing in the control you would like as the first parameter, and a Rect with the coordinates to make visible as the second.

Comment: Make sure that the rectangle is not null. It specifies the coordinate points of the visual to which it will scroll. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bencon/archive/2006/12/09/iscrollinfo-tutorial-part-iv.aspx